# How many ways are there to declare a two dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following as two ways to declare a two dimensional String array. I am being asked to find another way but I don't think there is any other way. Can someone please give me some advice.

```
    String[][] a = new String[20][20]
    String a[][] = new String[20][20]
```

Thanks

Comment: IMHO maybe you should get a book with Java basics. @siegi has posted the other way to declare arrays.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I cannot think of a Java basics book that would contain that sort of information. And if it would contain that information, it would be a bad book... ;)

Comment: Well I have books but I could not see any way. Sorry but I did try.

Comment: @brimborium it is in the Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide, chapter 3, as basic array declaration. Do you still think a book containing this info would be a bad one? :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually, yes. It's very confusing and I can not see any pro's on using that notation. The only reason to actually store this in my head is to impress someone else with useless java knowledge. :D But as always: If you show me a good use for it, I will take everything back. ;)

Comment: @brimborium it does not add any value, but its just another way to declare arrays. Why it exists? Ask Java designers, not me :). Should that be of knowledge in the books? I think yes, because its Java, after all.

Comment: @brimborium extracted from the book: "We can also declare multidimensional arrays, which are in fact arrays of arrays.
This can be done in the following manner: *String[][][] occupantName; // recommended [breakline] String[] ManagerName []; // yucky, but legal*".

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok, that's fine then. ;) Thanks for looking that up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] a[] = new String[20][20]
```

**Edit:** Note that this works with methods too:

```
private String[] a()[]
{
    return new String[20][20];
}
```

Also note that I do not recommend this notation as it is unclear and confusing!

Comment: Wow, did not know that. What a mess. :D

Comment: @brimborium Indeed… I didn't know that either until some weeks ago… :-D

Comment: Initialization, not declaration.

Comment: @user1458374 Sorry, I don't understand what you would like to say with that. The question *is* about *declaration* of two dimensional arrays…